# How can I run a command conditionally?

Tags: command-line

When running

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```

an example answer is the line

```
noop anticipatory deadline [cfq]
```

I want to write a script such that if the `cat` line answer contains

1. `deadline` then do **X**; or
2. If `deadline` doesn't appear, but it contains `noop` then do **Y**

So, how can I write a script that:

1. Checks the `cat` answer
2. In case of `deadline` does:

   ```
   sudo sed -i 's/^exit 0$/\necho deadline > \/sys\/block\/sda\/queue\/scheduler\necho 1 > \/sys\/block\/sda\/queue\/iosched\/fifo_batch\nexit 0/' /etc/rc.local
   ```
3. If `deadline` doesn't exist but 'noop' does then do:

   ```
   sudo sed -i 's/^exit 0$/\necho noop > \/sys\/block\/sda\/queue\/scheduler\nexit 0/' /etc/rc.local
   ```
4. Else nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to rc.local, above `exit 0`

```
SCHEDULER=$(cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler)

case "$SCHEDULER" in
    *deadline* )
        echo 'deadline' > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
        echo '1' > /sys/block/sda/queue/iosched/fifo_batch
        ;;
    *noop*)
        echo 'noop' > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
        ;;
    *)
        exit 0
esac
```

Run the script with sudo, or if it is an init script, it will run as root.

See also http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html

Comment: CLI in one line. maybe its somehow possible to translate this to CLI? in link i see theres mentioned awk i think somwhere saw it with something simmilar what could make it work.

Comment: bash, awk, python, you could probably script it in a number of ways. Either write a proper upstart script of make you life easier. In /etc/rc.local, just use an echo for each case, no real need to re-write rc.local with sed. See my updated script - much easier to read and understand.

Comment: So i put that in /etc/rc.local up before exit 0 ? I tryd this all in file ~/1.sh and executing gives $ ./1.sh 
./1.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `"$SCHEDULER"'
./1.sh: line 3: `case in "$SCHEDULER";'
then i put line #!/bin/sh -e from rc.local and executed $ ./1.sh 
./1.sh: 4: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")

Comment: $ bash 1.sh 
1.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `"$SCHEDULER"'
1.sh: line 3: `case in "$SCHEDULER";'

Comment: See update (remove the ;)

Comment: i now found little about sh and found case "$x" in so i changed to that from case in "$x" . it now doesnt give error using sudo ./1.sh but without sudo gives error for not having privilegies but working 
$ ./1.sh 
./1.sh: line 5: /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler: Permission denied
./1.sh: line 6: /sys/block/sda/queue/iosched/fifo_batch: Permission denied
So that means it works. THX.
BTW maybe in *noop*) needs space to make *noop* ) ?
is exit 0 also needed before esac if exit 0 is after this code in rc.local ? maybe this code can be put in default ubuntu ?